# Are whitespace-only display names allowed?

Tags: discussion, display-names

I came across a user that has a username consisting only of zero-width whitespace (just 3 U+3164 characters) and I'm not sure if this is ok or not. Obviously the user was able to enter it into the form, which gives me some doubt.

So I just wanted to check here rather than flagging for moderator attention. I couldn't find anything on MSO or MSE that specifically addressed this except for an [unanswered 7 year old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196407/why-are-usernames-allowed-to-be-composed-entirely-of-non-visible-unicode-charact).

Comment: I have a username like that.... it said it was ok for me.

Comment: Why is it a problem?

Comment: Give us a definition of "allowed".  "Allowed" as in "by the rules"?  I wouldn't imagine that whitespace-only names are offensive or derogatory.  Allowed as in "technically permitted"?  I feel like that's already answered.  Allowed as in "I can't flag this person"? You don't need their name to be able to flag either their comment or their posts.  What're you looking for?

Comment: Slightly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247022/zalgo-in-user-names-and-effects-on-comments-rendering

Comment: @Makoto I've seen a few questions about "bad" usernames – for example ones with Zalgo text – where they weren't blocked by the form, but SO realized they were not a good fit for the site (in that case, due to layout issues.)

Comment: @rene it kind of defeats the purpose of having a "display name" if there's nothing displayed...

Comment: I think in the case of Zalgo those actively interfered with the ability to select forms since the text rendered over the forms. I could see how those could be a problem.  Whitespace, though?  Not sure I see an issue...one's displayname is not a displayname which is very Meta indeed...

Comment: Looks like that user is my zalgo list: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/446741/how-do-i-query-sede-for-user-names-with-zalgo-unicode-abuse Only one so far.

Comment: If the link around that display name remains clickable... well, it's just another "creative" user name I guess.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385906/usernames-that-consist-solely-of-zalgo-text-cant-be-clicked-when-associated-wit)

Comment: Looks like I still can @-reply them (also still suggested for symbols-only username), and the whitespace is filled and hyperlinked, so there's still not a problem accessing the profile from comment.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi there is no link for the username (the whitespace is zero-width) but it's always available on the avatar.

Comment: @miken, I was thinking more about comments (and other venues like timelines, etc.), but Andrew confirms it works (at least in comments).

Comment: I just realized the question mentioned "zero-width", but on my Chrome 87 on Windows 10, it's full-width whitespace, that's why I didn't have any problem clicking it... //cc: @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: @rene:  Your Zalgo lists needs help if it's catching valid Vietnamese names as a sanity check...

Comment: @Andrew, well, if the user link is not clickable it becomes another matter than creativity (see Zoe's link). If the end result is breaking the UI, something should be done (not necessarily banning these user names, though).

Comment: If it's causing a distraction or hindrance, then it's a valid case to flag for moderator intervention. I won't promise to apply [the previously stated policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385906/usernames-that-consist-solely-of-zalgo-text-cant-be-clicked-when-associated-wit#comment702511_385906), but this is clearly not a legitimate user name, so I see no reason why we need to allow it.

Comment: @Makoto oh boy. Did you look at that [monster query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277871/158100)? Do you wanna hurt me?

Comment: @Cody, re: your policy, I would recommend *Unexpected EOF* in this case. The target user may even keep that name.

Comment: @rene:  I did, and I know that it's going to be hard to do this.  It's a useful heuristic but I would feel some type of way if my perfectly valid name came up in something like a Zalgo list just because someone popularized the excessive spamming of diacritics and other character extensions.  But this is more of an off-hand remark; I respect the difficulty of creating this expression at all.

Comment: Unanswered, but related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326747/disallow-user-names-which-result-in-unclickable-links

Comment: One reason why it might be a "problem" is: from my point of view, when you read a post or a comment, you don't immediately know who you are talking with without having to open their profile (if you can open their profile). What if you have a thread consisting of several NoNamers? That can quickly become chaotic in my opinion. Even worse if you get a rude NoNamer which you mistake for another one NoNamer.

Comment: Man, imagine if you'd linked to the user account in question so we could actually see, because I assume the name has been changed by now. And nitpick: U+3164 is not technically whitespace according to Unicode, hence why SO's check (which I assume is using the standard `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` method in .NET and hence https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=net-5.0#remarks) did not disallow it.

Comment: @IanKemp Speaking of nitpicking, when I used to be on Internet Explorer, I found a way to generate over a dozen different unicode characters (which I can't do on Firefox), all of which appeared as "zero width whitespaces". I'm thinking that targeting some specific characters wouldn't be enough, unless someone can be sure to have a catalogue of every single possible invisible characters.

Comment: @Clockwork I'm not advocating that SO change their check, because it's not their fault that people are abusing Unicode - most of the names from rene's query are perfectly legitimate. I think it's fine to have the community keep a look-out and bring up such abuse on a case-by-case basis, exactly as done here. We should, however, consider adding a note in the Help Centre that anyone trying to be "clever" with usernames and Unicode may find their account liable to be suspended or banned.

Comment: @IanKemp yes I flagged based on comments here, and it's since been changed back to "userxxxx". I didn't want to seem like I was trying to "shame" anyone so I left the user out of it.

Comment: @IanKemp To be fair, I already went through rene's queue and made some "adjustments" to the invalid names. :-) But yeah, I agree with your larger point. It's both technically difficult and practically unnecessary to put system-level blocks in place. I prefer to just handle this sort of thing with human discretion.

Comment: @CodyGray would you mind posting an answer that says there won't be technical blocks but we should flag on a case-by-case basis? Just so we have something on record for future searches and I can close this question?

Comment: @miken32 Questions aren't closed on Stack sites unless they're off-topic or unanswerable.

Comment: @Scratte fine, "resolved." I have 30k rep and a number of Steward badges, I am familiar with how the network works ;)

Comment: Displaying nothing is not nothing

Comment: "zero-width whitespace (just 3 U+3164 characters)" - U+3164 is not zero-width whitespace, it is unicode char "HANGUL FILLER", which appears to render as a very wide whitespace character. @AndrewT.

Comment: "it's since been changed back to 'userxxxx'" - If you do a user search for 3 x U+3164 chars on SO then you find 6 users that have a seemingly _blank_ username.

Comment: @MrWhite I was assuming it was zero width based on the fact that there wasn't a clickable link for the display name. If I go to, for example, https://unicode-table.com/en/3164/ I'm unable to select anything where the character is. May be font/system/browser dependent? I'm on a Mac.

Comment: @miken32 Curious, it's selectable for me on Chrome/Windows and Safari/Firefox on iPadOS. (I don't have Mac.)

Comment: Definitely related; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359283/its-possible-to-create-empty-content-fields-p/359345#359345

Answer (score 27):

The whole point of having a display name is to facilitate the easy identification of users you're interacting with. If there were no desire for that, the site would make display names entirely optional. The fact that they have not tells me that display names should be made to follow some kind of rule to make them useful.

My thought, for an answer to this "problem" (I am using that word very lightly here) is that we can organize a list of whitespace, zero-width, zalgo characters, etc. A simple check can be done for the number of such characters in the display name. If there are 6 of these things and no other characters, it's a good indication that this is not a particularly helpful display name. If there are 6 of them, but 15 other "regular" characters, then it's likely to be part of a valid display name, or maybe just ornamentation added to one.

Obviously this could be a cat-and-mouse game; what about punctuation, what about subscript characters, yadda yadda. This doesn't need to be perfect though, just good enough to catch out the most confusing usernames at the source. The rest can be left for flagging if needed.

Comment: H E N R Y the V

Comment: I don't think display names are that useful for *display*. You can still recognize a user by the avatar, or by the whitespace, sort of like that xkcd joke where 11II1I1 is an easily recognizable license plate consisting of 1s and Is. But perhaps the more important use is being able to mention someone in a tag.

Comment: @Muz I'm thinking about the case where you have several NoNamers commenting on a post. There's no avatar nor reputation to tell who's who in that case.

Comment: This can't be specific to Stack Exchange. Aren't there some standard solutions?

Answer (score 21):

I maintain the same position I've already expressed in similar answer to the same problem with "zalgo" names: [Usernames that consist solely of Zalgo text can't be clicked when associated with a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385906/usernames-that-consist-solely-of-zalgo-text-cant-be-clicked-when-associated-wit/385949#385949).

There are almost endless amount of combinations in Unicode that can produce unreadable results. Instead of maintaining an ever-growing blacklist or introducing a restrictive white list, the problem can and should be fixed by carefully designing userlink-area style with relevant defaults like min/max-width/height, so it is always visible and always properly constrained, regardless of whatever name the user chooses for themself.

Comment: I read a comment on that other answer which mentioned we can't just ban non-latin characters. But, somehow, on Steam, you can have unicode filled nicknames. But when you try to have a blank name, it automatically replaces it with some alt text.

Comment: @Clockwork: Unicode may have many characters, but the standard also contains many auxiliary tables with character attributes and classes. And it **is** feasible to base rules on these classes, because that's a much smaller set. For instance, Steam probably bans names that are all Unicode class `WS` (Whitespace).

Comment: @MSalters unless it is really tight and restrictive whitelist, I'll find a way to build an unreadable text under any rules. If your goal is to make "always visible clickable username box", then just do JUST THAT - get CSS and make an "always visible clickable username box" instead of fiddling with something else - i.e. a text within.

Answer (score 8):

A few quick thoughts concerning  rene's comment "why is it a problem".

The main question from a front-end perspective is whether it creates confusion or problems for other users, like whitespace-only file names cause in *nix (it's not clear that there is a file and it interacts badly with the shell command processing).

Most user interaction with SE is through the web site with graphic rendering. Possible issues that come to mind there:

- **You can not view the user profile** because the whitespace-only user name is not a recognizable click target. The click may even be hard or impossible for zero-width names. (I just saw that such an issue appears with empty answers, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359321/261639. Conceivable with user names in certain contexts as well.) But you can always click on the logo so that there is always a significant surface to click on.
- **You cannot distinguish between different whitespace-only names.**
  That is perhaps mildly confusing. But generally user names are not unique anyway (which I, by the way, find mightily confusing and a design flaw, not least because I have the common German name *Peter Schneider).* User names are simply not first class data here.
- **It is confusing as such** (where is the user name? what is this? etc.) Given the relatively clear and consistent layout of posts and the mandatory presence of a user icon I think the degree of confusion is not terrible and more than compensated for by the realization that it is a little smart prank. This assessment is partly based on the assumption that the SE audience is above-average familiar with computer user interfaces.

So I don't think it's terrible.

Comment: What do you mean by "*nix"? The unix based operating systems?

Comment: Why do you think a user from cooking.stackexchange.com would have "above-average" familiarity with obscure Unicode characters?

Comment: @miken32 Because they discuss cooking ... on an online gamefied discussion board? Something my mother and my father wouldn't do. Without those indigerati the SE population is above average computer savvy. Plus: The top SE substacks are stackoverflow and mathematics, not cooking and christianity, leading to a corresponding selection bias. Oh: I didn't mean familiarity with Korean Unicode codepoints -- I didn't know anything about them before today. I meant *general* familiarity with computers so that you recognize when a mouse pointer changes shape etc.

Comment: @Clockwork Yes. Or, more precise, Unix (TM) *like* -- some copyright holders would mind if you *based* your OS on Unix (TM). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like.

Comment: You've given workarounds for the usability problems. Can you give some explanation as to the *advantages*?

Comment: Are your mother and father not on Facebook? Mine are. I know SO is the elephant in the room here, but SE is a very broad network of sites.

Comment: @miken32 I would suggest that use of Facebook and use of StackExchange would be inversely correlated, if anything. The statement that StackExchange users (regardless of "home site") are typically more tech-savvy than the average human seems remarkably non-controversial to me.

Comment: @Sellyme based on number of users, sure – because the techy sites have such overwhelming user numbers. My point is that they aren't the *only* sites in the network and we shouldn't forget that. The argument I was pushing back on is that you have to have some kind of "computer savvy" to effectively use Cooking or ELL. It's just a web site, like Facebook.

Comment: @miken32 My mother in law is, my own parents aren't. But managing facebook on an iphone is not the epitome of computer savviness.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, it's a nice hack for one, probably the main "advantage". But I suppose the main reason to actively forbid something which is by default fine with the site's technical infrastructure is that it has prohibitive usability or other technical disadvantages. (I only discussed frontend problems -- are there any backend problems?).

Comment: @CodyGray By the way, why did you delete the much-upvoted whitespace-only post? I thought it was really funny. It actually is also an answer because it shows both the prank and its disadvantages (you can't read anything, you are a bit puzzled for a second).

Comment: Because it didn't answer the question. The bug it was attempting to report was already posted as [a separate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404307).